# Why is this stored velocity changing?

Tags: unity, c#

```
    public void OnGamePause()
{
    Debug.Log("OnGamePause in PauseController");

    if (rb != null)
    {
        velocity = rb.velocity;
        angularVelocity = rb.angularVelocity;
        Debug.Log("Pause vel. = " + velocity + "Avel. = " + angularVelocity);
        rb.Sleep();
        Paused = true;
    }
}

public void OnGameResume()
{
    Debug.Log("OnGameResume in PauseController");

    if (rb != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Resume vel. = " + velocity + "Avel. = " + angularVelocity);
        rb.velocity = velocity;
        rb.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;

        rb.WakeUp();
        Paused = false;
    }
}
```

[image: Console]

Can anyone give me any idea what might be changing velocity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I was just calling OnGamePause many times due to not limiting input.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and mark this answer as the accepted one in a couple of days :)

Answer (score 0):

Where does OnGamePause come from? the unity documentation reads OnApplicationPause, which is called twice, so i believe that's what causing it. 
Try copying the vector into a new Vector3, and check if it's set before you do so:

```
Vector3 velocity = velocity == null ? new Vector3(rb.velocity) : velocity;
```

also, i don't think the rb.sleep() and rb.wakeup() are necessary when pausing the game. check this link out: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html

Comment: OnGamePause is my own function. It's just called from user input which it turns out I haden't prevented form just calling it repeatedly.